# Extra Positional Argument in Flutter/Firebase when trying to access document field

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to print a specific users info from firebase, but whenever I try to call the specific value, such as name, it always comes up as the error, Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.

```
getUserState() async{
  String temp;
  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;   
  final String id = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').id;
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(id).get().then((value){
    temp = value.data('name') as String;
    
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

`data` is a method that takes no parameter and returns a `Map`

Try this:

```
    temp = value.data()!['name'] as String;
```

Answer (score 0):

To print an specific user information from Firebase calling by a value such as name, you can use the Firebase Database Query API. You can use the orderByChild() method to query the database and retrieve data based on a specific value. For example, if you want to print an user information from Firebase calling by name, you can use the following code:

```dart
    // Get a reference to the database
    var database = firebase.database();
    
    // Query the database for user information based on name
    var query = database.ref("users").orderByChild("name").equalTo("John Doe");
    
    // Get the user information from the query
    query.once("value", function(snapshot) {
      var userInfo = snapshot.val();
    
      // Print the user information
      console.log(userInfo);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.get` to read map

```dart
 temp = value.get('name') as String? ?? "" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a function that returns a String that contains the name you can refactor your code like the following:

```
  Future<String?> getUserState(String userId) async {
    final docRef = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userId).get();
    final user = docRef.data();
    return user?['name'];
  }
```

*user*: is a Map<String, dynamic> representation of your document in collection. You can use it to covert in your model with fromJson for example.

If any users found with provided id it returns null